# Add DNS alt names to certificates in Puppet

Tags: dns, puppet, ca

I have two networks and in both of them I'm using Puppet to manage the configuration. The second network, an extension of the first one, have it's own CA in which I'm using autosign. I have several nodes there and I'm trying to use some proxies I have on the first network. Obviously, this proxies will need a valid certificate from each CA.

To get a certificate from the second network CA I've defined an exec resource in the proxies manifests in which I use an invalid environment. That way I get the certificate but that puppet agent run is not finished. So far so good.

The tricky part now is that I need these new certificates to have some DNS alt names. As far as I know I have to add the option dns_alt_names in second network CA's puppet.conf, but this is not an option for two reasons:

1. All the certificates (even those of non-proxy nodes) will have these alt names.
2. Alternative names are disallowed by default so I have to sign the certificates manually using --allow-dns-alt-names.

Any alternative/solution on how to do this?

Comment: didn't exactly understand your structure, but I guess you could install puppet master as rails application with external web server like apache or nginx, then try to play with virtual hosts with different certificate chains. to use same code on both webservers it can be linked by ``ln -s``.

Answer (score 0):

Puppet supports dns alt names when you sign your certs. That's part of the documentation for multimaster setups:

https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppetserver/5.3/scaling_puppet_server.html#creating-and-configuring-compile-masters

```
curl -k https://[your master]:8140/packages/current/install.bash | sudo bash -s main:dns_alt_names=<COMMA-SEPARATED LIST OF ALT NAMES FOR THE PUPPET MASTER>
```

> From the command line of <MASTER.EXAMPLE.COM>, run
> puppet cert --allow-dns-alt-names sign example.master.example.com.